# Graphical Selection of Data in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, plot, interactive

**The Problem to Solve**

I have two 2D numpy arrays. One of which is an array of floats, the other is an array of strings. Each float array element is extracted from a file with a name in the corresponding string array element.

I want to plot a 2D heatmap of the array of floats, with the color corresponding to the magnitude of the array element.

Based on this I would like to interactively select an area (e.g. with a polygon or lasso tool). I want the indices of the array which have been selected to then be written to a list/array so the corresponding filenames can be extracted for further processing.

I am using Python 3.

I have spent several hours trying to make headway with this problem in Bokeh but have had no success.

**My Questions are the following**

Which Python libraries best suit this problem?

Given the above library(s), do you have any tips to get started?

**Many thanks.**

*Note: I have been using Python for some scientific data programming but would not consider myself an experienced programmer.*

Comment: perhaps share some example data and your first tries with Bokeh

Comment: look at http://glueviz.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, however it is quite doable with matplotlib. Matplotlib has two classes SpanSelector and LassoSelector that you can use.You can find some documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html). [Here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html) is an example with LassoSelector.

Comment: This was just what I needed to know. I solved the problem using matplotlib based on the examples suggested as I decided it would be more useful to me in the both the short and long term to develop knowledge of matplotlib as opposed to Bokeh and Glue.